# archive-{$post_type}.php not loading. instead the default archive.php loads

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

My `has-archive` is set to true in the `register_post_type`. My `archive-portfolio.php` exists. I've tried flushing rewrite rules. I've tried a lot of other stuff, and after every step, I reset/saved/resaved/refreshed my permalink structure.

This is my `register_post_type`

```
register_post_type( 'portfolio',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Portfolio Items' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio Item' ),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio Item')
        ),
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'
        ),
    'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => true),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'slug' => 'portfolio',
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
    'hierarchical' => false
    )
);
```

Whenever I click on a category that a "portfolio" type post belongs to, WP loads the default `archive.php`. How can I get it to load the `archive-portfolio.php`?
Or how can I find out, in the `archive.php` if the user is browsing the default post category archives, or the portfolio category archives?

Comment: Please do not post duplicates. File an [edit] if you need to post additional info. Please see [ask] and [help] and learn how stacks like this operate

Comment: Also, please do not use multiple accounts. Please see [how to merge multiple accounts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Don't get yourself blocked and trashed for duplicate accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Category archive pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#category) do not use `archive-{$post_type}.php` type templates. Instead they use `category-{$category->slug}.php`, `category-{$category->term_id}.php`, `category.php`, `archive.php` or `index.php` depending on the first available template in the hierarchy.

An easy fix would be to just make a copy of `archive-{$post_type}.php` and renaming it to `category.php`. WordPress will automatically use this template when youn visit a category page. From what I can gather from your question, you have already use `pre_get_posts` to add your custom post type to category and tag archives.

The long fix, should you decide that you really really need to use `archive-{$post_type}.php`, is to make use of the `category_template` filter to tell WordPress to use this template and not the other templates that might be available in the hierarchy

```
add_filter( 'category_template', function ( $template )
{
    // Try to locate our new desired template
    $locate_template = locate_template( 'archive-portfolio.php' );

    // If our desired template is not found, bail
    if ( !$locate_template )
        return $template;

    // Our desired template exists, load it
    return $locate_template;
});
```

### EXTRA IMPORTANT INFO

If you are in any means using a custom query to include your custom post type into your tag and category archives, remove that custom query and go back to the default loop: (***NOTE:*** The same applies to the home page and `index.php`)

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

            // Add your mark up and template tags

    }
}
```

You should not be seeing any custom post type posts now when you visit a category or tag archive page. To include the custom post type posts, we will use `pre_get_posts` to add your custom post type to category and tag archive pages

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin()         // Only target front pages
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
         && (    $q->is_category() // Target category archives OR
              || $q->is_tag()      // Target tag achives OR
              || $q->is_home()     // Target the home page
            )
    ) {
        $q->set( 'post_ype', ['post', 'portfolio'] );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem by registering a custom taxonomy "portfolio_category" for the custom post type "portfolio" and creating a template "taxonomy-portfolio_category.php" which will serve as a seperate category archive for my custom post type.